# Loop through pages by controlling the pageNo on the url

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

Very new to python and in need of help on how to properly loop through a link by incrementing the pageNo value on the url i need to scrape then continuously append the results to df

Below is what I have.

The link is behind a login wall but hoping that you don't need that to look into my code.

Thank you in advance!

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import time
from pymongo import MongoClient

#database
client = MongoClient("xxx")
db = client["xxx"]
collection = db["xxx"]

# launch WMS
url = "https://xxx.inserdomain.com/solution/login.htm"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)

#Login start
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("xxx")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("xxx")

driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
#login end

# open shipments page
pageSize = 200
pageNo = 0
currentView = 34448
url2 = "https://xxx.insertdomain.com/solution/entitylist.htm?entityName=Shipment&tabName=Shipment&pageNo={pageNo}&pageSize={pageSize}&currentViewId={currentView}".format(pageNo=pageNo, pageSize=pageSize, currentView=currentView)
driver.get(url2)
html = driver.page_source

dfs = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"class":"roundedTable"}, header=5)

for df in dfs:
    df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns", inplace=True),
    df.drop("No", axis="columns", inplace=True),
    df.dropna(how='all', axis=0, inplace=True),
    print(df.to_json(orient="index"))

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_dict = df.to_dict("records")
collection.insert_many(df_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below loops through 100 pages (0 - 99 inclusive). You can use break to exit the loop.

```
for pageNo in range(100): # replace 100 with the maximum page number  
    url2 = "https://rby.deposco.com/solution/entitylist.htm?entityName=Shipment&tabName=Shipment&pageNo={pageNo}&pageSize={pageSize}&currentViewId={currentView}".format(pageNo=pageNo, pageSize=pageSize, currentView=currentView)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that! follow up question: 
any idea how i can properly append the results per page?
im trying to save the results in in a CSV file but it's only saving the last page in the file created.

Comment: If you're creating if from the dataframe you'll need to us df.append to add each page worth's in.